# Bootstrap carousel next and prev function not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

Using latest version and have the basic carousel. I've got it working with all the default settings, however when trying to add or stop certain functions, things break or don't work at all. I want to be able to manually cycle through the images. Don't want it to auto cycle. I want to just use the next and prev buttons to cycle through. I've read a few post on here but the solutions don't work help/work.

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">

<!-- Carousel items -->
<div class="carousel-inner">
<div class="active item">
     <ul class="thumbnails">
         <li>Img</li>
         <li>Img</li>
         <li>Img</li>
     </ul>
</div>
<div class="item">
      <ul class="thumbnails">
         <li>Img</li>
         <li>Img</li>
         <li>Img</li>
     </ul>
</div>
</div>
<!-- Carousel nav -->
<a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
<a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
</div>

$('#myCarousel').each(function() {
    $(this).carousel({
        interval: false
    });
});
```

Comment: "not working" can be vague. Any errors or specific ways of not working?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can wire the events up yourself:

```
$('.carousel-control.left').click(function() {
  $('#myCarousel').carousel('prev');
});

$('.carousel-control.right').click(function() {
  $('#myCarousel').carousel('next');
});
```

You can of course use the `data-slide` as well just depends on what you want to do.  Something like this which does the same as above.

```
$('a[data-slide="prev"]').click(function() {
  $('#myCarousel').carousel('prev');
});

$('a[data-slide="next"]').click(function() {
  $('#myCarousel').carousel('next');
});
```

Comment: But do you have to wire them up yourself...I thought that the Bootstrap carousel didn't require that.

Comment: You can use the data-slide as indicated in my answer although at that time I don't know if there were some bugs or something that prevented the prev/next from working when the interval was turned off.

Comment: Being a SO newbie, I was unable to directly comment to this answer with my edited code. See below for a slight tweak that 'disables' the prev/next links working as inline page anchors (thus moving the whole page as well as the slide ;) )!

Comment: So useful, buddy.

Answer (score 3):

I had some difficulty pasting code in a comment (newbie :) ) but I took Lucuma's post and added some code to prevent both previous and next links from working as a inline page anchor. Using the code below, you stop that from happening but still slide backwards/forwards like you wanted.

```
// Fixes the prev/next links of the sliders
$('.carousel-control.left').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  $('.js-carousel').carousel('prev');
  return false;
});

$('.carousel-control.right').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  $('.js-carousel').carousel('next');
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this, i was getting that inline page anchor issue.