# Why my prev/next buttons doesn't work for this bootstrap carousel?

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm trying to create a bootstrap carousel for my Home page. My problem is that the Prev/Next buttons doesn't work and the carousel doesn't slide images automatically.

here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>


        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">


  <style>

      .carousel-inner > .item > img,
      .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
          width:640px;
          height:360px;
          margin:auto;
      }


      ul{
            list-style-type: none;
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            overflow:hidden;
            background-color:#335;
        }

        li{
            float:left;
        }

        li a{
            display:block;
            color:white;
            text-align:center;
            padding: 14px 16px;
            text-decoration:none;
        }

        li a:hover{
            background-color:#111;
        }


        div{
            display:block;
        }


        body{
            background-color:#fff5cc;
        }




  </style>
    </head>


    <body>

        <ul>
            <li><a class="active" ui-sref="home()">Home</a></li>
            <li><a ui-sref="companies()">Insurance Companies</a></li>
            <li><a ui-sref="clients()">Clients</a></li>
            <li><a ui-sref="cars()">Cars</a></li>
            <li><a ui-sref="about()">About</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="container">

            <br>

            <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" style="width:800px; margin: 0 auto">

                <ol class="carousel-indicators">

                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>

                </ol>


                <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

                    <div class="item active">
                        <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" 
                            alt="FirstImage" width="460" height="345">
                    </div>

                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="http://www.ourbusinessladder.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/How-to-start-an-insurance-company-org-848x315.jpg" alt="SecondImage" width="460" heigth="345">
                    </div>

                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="http://www.azoft.com/images/case-studies/mobile-application-for-insurance-company.jpg" 
                        alt="ThirdImage" width="460" height="345">
                    </div>

                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="http://www.ourbusinessladder.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/How-to-start-an-insurance-company-org-848x315.jpg" 
                        alt="FourthImage" width="460" height="345">
                    </div>

                </div>

                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>

                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>

            </div>
        </div>


        <div>

            <h1 style="color:blue; font-family:verdana; text-align:center">Save Money with Auto Insurance Discounts!!!</h1>
            <h1 style="color:tomato; font-family:times new roman; text-align:center">Auto Insurance Options That Keep You Covered!!!</h1>

        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

I'm mentioning that this is only the part of code where I'm trying to create my carousel. I'm working in Cloud9 and when I'm loading only my HTML page, the carousel works fine, but after I'm starting the Node.js server and going in Home state the buttons doesn't work.

Here is my index.html where I'm loading all libs:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    
    <head>
        
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        
        <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0-rc.2/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.2/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-messages/1.6.0/angular-messages.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
        integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
        
    </head>
    
    <body ng-app="insurancesApp">
        <div ui-view></div>
    </body>
    
</html>
```

Comment: please provide a working fiddle

Comment: We probably can't help without the actual jQuery code. Also, do you have any console errors?

Comment: give us the complete code containing your style codes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap carousel next and prev function not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15819943/bootstrap-carousel-next-and-prev-function-not-working)

Comment: @Matheno, I haven't console errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use bootstrap with angularjs best way is https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Next time please be more specific what you are trying to do.

I think this works you just missing something, you provides not all code so it is hard to say what's missing. I have done this and this works ok.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

  <style>

      .carousel-inner > .item > img,
      .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
          width:640px;
          height:360px;
          margin:auto;
      }


      ul{
            list-style-type: none;
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            overflow:hidden;
            background-color:#335;
        }

        li{
            float:left;
        }

        li a{
            display:block;
            color:white;
            text-align:center;
            padding: 14px 16px;
            text-decoration:none;
        }

        li a:hover{
            background-color:#111;
        }


        div{
            display:block;
        }


        body{
            background-color:#fff5cc;
        }




  </style>
    </head>


    <body>

        <ul>
            <li><a class="active" ui-sref="home()">Home</a></li>
            <li><a ui-sref="companies()">Insurance Companies</a></li>
            <li><a ui-sref="clients()">Clients</a></li>
            <li><a ui-sref="cars()">Cars</a></li>
            <li><a ui-sref="about()">About</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="container">

            <br>

            <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" style="width:800px; margin: 0 auto">

                <ol class="carousel-indicators">

                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>

                </ol>


                <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

                    <div class="item active">
                        <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" 
                            alt="FirstImage" width="460" height="345">
                    </div>

                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="http://www.ourbusinessladder.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/How-to-start-an-insurance-company-org-848x315.jpg" alt="SecondImage" width="460" heigth="345">
                    </div>

                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="http://www.azoft.com/images/case-studies/mobile-application-for-insurance-company.jpg" 
                        alt="ThirdImage" width="460" height="345">
                    </div>

                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="http://www.ourbusinessladder.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/How-to-start-an-insurance-company-org-848x315.jpg" 
                        alt="FourthImage" width="460" height="345">
                    </div>

                </div>

                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>

                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>

            </div>
        </div>


        <div>

            <h1 style="color:blue; font-family:verdana; text-align:center">Save Money with Auto Insurance Discounts!!!</h1>
            <h1 style="color:tomato; font-family:times new roman; text-align:center">Auto Insurance Options That Keep You Covered!!!</h1>

        </div>
  <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I've edited the post and now all code is provided. I've changed my code, but doesn't work.

Comment: I run it, but in my app it doesn't work. I'm loading the library for bootstrap and angular from an index.html page. I will edit my post and provide the index.html. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do my carousel, also Saulius is right make sure all your bootstrap content is correctly linked whether you download it or link it. Your jquery, js and bootstrap css have to be current or the js for the carousel won't work. Linking bootstrap to your html info is on their website.

```
<div class="slideshow-container-home">


<div class="mySlides fade">
<div href="something.html">
<img src="img1.jpg" class="home-slide"></img>
<div class="text"></div>
</div>

</div>
<div class="mySlides fade">
<div href="something.html">
<img src="img2.jpg" class="home-slide"></img>
<div class="text"></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
<div href="something.html">
<img src="img3.jpg" class="home-slide"></img>
<div class="text"></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
<div href="something.html">
<img src="img4.jpg" class="home-slide"></img>
<div class="text"></div>
</div>
</div>




<div class="mySlides fade">
<div href="something.html">
<img src="img5.jpg" class="home-slide"></img>
<div class="text"></div>
</div>
</div>


<a class="prev-home" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a>
<a class="next-home" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a>

</div>
<div class="dot-container-home">
<div style="text-align:center;">
<span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
<span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
<span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
<span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span>
<span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(5)"></span>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved my problem. I've modified the order of link to jQuery, css, angularJS etc libs in my index.html and now everything is working fine. 
Here is my index.html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
        <script src="https://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0-rc.2/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.2/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-messages/1.6.0/angular-messages.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
        integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous"> 

    </head>

    <body ng-app="insurancesApp">
        <div ui-view></div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Thank you!

Comment: My suggestion still if you doing thing in angularjs use angular and its extensions do not mix bunch of things. Coz sometimes it is hard to make play nice with each other I mean event propagation end etc.